# How do you package up a visual studio aws serverless project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can package up an aws serverless project in an automated way so that we can split our build and release pipeline up.

Using the `dotnet lambda` command line tools, I can see there is a `dotnet lambda package` command to package the lambda as a .zip file ready for deployment. But I can't find anything for packaging the whole serverless application up.

Is this possible? If so what commands do I run?

We're running on VSTS for the Build and Release pipelines, however I don't really think I makes any difference as long as I can script it out.

Comment: The key phrase is `visual studio aws serverless project`. Did you install the [Visual Studio AWS Toolkit](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/)? It contains [AWS Serverless project templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-index.html). As for creating .NET Core projects from the command line, the relevant command is `dotnet new whatever`. Once you install the toolkit run `dotnet new` without arguments in a console to list the names of the new templates

Comment: [This guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-dotnet-coreclr-deployment-package.html) shows how to install the AWS templates from the commandline

Comment: I've already created the project and can deploy it using the right click project and `Publish to AWS Lambda` in visual studio or by running `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless`, however I want this to build run as a multiple steps on our build server, so step 1 - "build the C# code and package artifacts", Step 2 - "Deploy to DevTest stack", Step 3 - "Deploy to Production Stack"

Comment: You didn't ask how to configure your XYZ build server to run a build script. Which build server are you using? Does it support .NET commands, scripts, batches? Worst case you can create a `build.cmd` file with the commands.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which build environment I'm running, ideally I want to use cake, but that can drop back to using any old command. I'll update the question with more clarity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this is possible by packaging up the lambda function into a zip file with the `dotnet lambda package` command and then copying across the `serverless.template` file to be used later.

```
dotnet lambda package
```

Once we've got our `*.zip` and our `serverless.template` handy we can then run the `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless` with the following arguments:

```
dotnet lambda deploy-serverless --package .\drop\MyApp.zip --template .\drop\serverless.template
```