# How to Deploy dotnet core functions using the Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am finding it a challenge to properly package and deploy dotnet functions (using dotnet core 2.1 runtime) utilizing Serverless to AWS Lambda. I am not finding any examples other than ones that use the SAM and dotnet deploy lambda-serverless commands.

Example: [How do you package up a visual studio aws serverless project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449530/how-do-you-package-up-a-visual-studio-aws-serverless-project/50453340#50453340)

Using command line and Serverless, what needs to be done to properly deploy a dotnet core function to AWS Lambda? Is this even possible using the Serverless Framework?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to overcome my issues.

1. cd into .csproj folder
2. `dotnet restore`
3. `dotnet lambda package` using dotnet lambda tools `dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools`
4. Assuming the rest of your serverless.ymal is set up correctly, make sure your serverless.yml has a package property with an artifact that points to the .zip file generated by dotnet lambda package, for example:

```
package:
  artifact: ./<projectFolderName>/src/<projectName>/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/<zipFileName>.zip
```

5. You need a Lambda Entry Point class (e.g. LambdaEntryPoint.cs) that uses a Startup class:

LambdaEntryPoint.cs example

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
    {
        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }

        ...
}
```

Startup.cs example

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
    /// </summary>
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

    }
}
```

Note: some of this can be generated from templates.

6. do a regular `sls deploy`

Outside of what is readily available on the Internet, these steps highlight some of the hurdles I had to overcome to get mine working.